# DNN error setting site to HTTPS

Tags: https, dotnetnuke

I inherited a DNN site running on DNN 5.  We have been asked to turn on ssl and from everything I've seen it should be as simple as flipping the secure flag in the admin module.  however when we do this and try to save we get the following error.

```
Message: DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: Input string was 
not in a correct format. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not 
in a correct format. at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles 
options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) at 
System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) at    
DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin.Portals.SiteSettings.cmdUpdate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Lots of stuff on Google for this but nothing I've seen so far relating to the https flag.   Anyone run across this one before and any ideas on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save in the site settings module, it tries to update/parse all of the settings.  So, even though you're setting the HTTPS setting, it's probably an unrelated setting that is causing the error.  I'd investigate the results you're finding on Google more.

You might also want to upgrade DNN to a later version (I vaguely remember some issue with bad data causing an issue like this during some version 5 upgrades; I believe it was fixed if you keep upgrading to DNN 5.6.x or DNN 6.x).

Comment: Thanks.  That's kind of what I suspected but unfortunately none of us have worked with DNN.   We're trying to get a working dev site in place then we can try an upgrade.   If that fails then it is a couple weeks of long nights replacing the site.